# How to persist NSColor? There is no alloc for it such as e.g. UIColor alloc

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-management, allocation

I am trying to port working iPhone code to the Mac (iOS to OSX - I believe?)

The working iPhone version is

```
...
return [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1.0f];
}
```

The non-working Mac attempt is

```
...
return [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1.0f];
}
```

But when I later access the container, the NSColor is not there. But when I try various versions of [NSColor alloc], none of them "work".

My question is, how do I create an NSColor that persists (so that later, I have to de-allocate it)?

Comment: Usually you don't want to call dealloc on it.  Use release instead because some other part of the app may have retained it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to retain your color in your mac attempt.  You are calling a function that returns an autoreleased object.  You need to either keep calling this function every time you want a color or do something like this:

```
return [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1.0f] retain];
```

Comment: Thanks to all three answers - the last fits best because the colour is returned to a C++ container in C++ function and so that cannot use "self". Later the colour is released and now it all works OK. Many thanks!

Comment: Robin, while this may work for you now, in the future the object ownership policy is a very good thing to follow where possible, as mentioned in Jacob's answer.

Comment: Good point, I had "read" but not absorbed Jacob's answer - now I get it. (Apple encourage "speed reading" by their use of, e.g. in their Object Ownership Policy, phrases such as "This is primarily an implicit corollary of the previous policy rules, made explicit." - I would have used "i.e." instead, being bit of a simpleton :)

Answer (score 9):

`NSColor`'s `+colorWith` methods return an autoreleased `NSColor` instance, so in order to obtain ownership of the object, you can send it the `retain` message.

```
-(NSColor *) getSomeColor {
   return [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:1.0f];
}
//...
//somewhere else...
myColor = [[self getSomeColor] retain];
```

Another point worth mentioning is that according to the **[Object Ownership Policy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html)**, you should ***not*** return an object with a *retain count* > 0 from a method that does not have the words `alloc`, `new` or `copy`.

So in this case, you *should* return the autoreleased `NSColor` and send it the `retain` message on the receiving end.

Answer (score 3):

The key here is that you need to own the object. `alloc` is one message that confers ownership. `retain` is another. You need to `retain` the color.